# is it better to overwrite data in memory or to read first for checking

Tags: java, android, memory-management, sharedpreferences

My question is particularly for android. I am using shared preferences to save some data locally on the device. Each time I make a call to server, the response may be new or it may be the same stuff I already persisted. Without changing the question as asked, what is a better design?

**one:** check if the data is not there and then add it?

```
if(!getFromSharedPrefs(dataKey).equals(newData)){
  addToSharedPrefs(dataKey, newData);
}
```

Or **two:** simply add the new data each time as overwriting is not more expensive than reading?

```
addToSharedPrefs(dataKey, newData);
```

Please include explanation as to why it's better to check first or as to why the two approaches are equivalent.

I am assuming the answer is platform or device agnostic, so if you know objective-c or java or whatever, it should not matter (?)

Comment: Let me clarify that whichever approach I take may end up being called 200 times or more per day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Number 2. Here's why: (Assuming addToSharedPrefs(...) is simply updating the reference in a map-ish data structure and not doing some further network calls or extensive computation, which wouldn't make sense, but just in case...) You're retrieving either way, which is expensive, but the first way also calls equals() on your data object, which can be costly, it's probably not a huge difference, but this way you're eliminating that.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I don't understand how `retrieving either` make the two approaches equivalent. Yes, I am retrieving in both cases, but only in the second case am I writing. Is that not some saving for case 1? Or are you saying that the saving for case 1 is not significant. Let me clarify that whichever approach I take may end up being called 200 times or more per day.

Comment: Just read the question again. I thought this was all happening in memory, and that the addToSharedPrefs was writing to memory, not flash. In your actual case you're more than likely better off with #1, unless your equals() method does some crazy time intensive stuff. IMHO 200 times per day isn't much at all. If it's interrupting the user experience that would be a problem, but if this is happening in the background your driving cost (by orders of magnitude) is the network call to retrieve data from the server, and you're doing it in either case.